# I'll be 60 years old next year

Tags: phrases

Do you say "I'll become 60 years old" or "I am becoming 60 years old?"

Comment: Just like your title: You'll *be* 60 next year.  Alternatively you can say you're *turning* 60 next year.

Comment: You may be interested in our companion site: [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic on ELU because it is basic; it should be migrated to the English Language Learners site [(ELL)](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Mari-LouA: ELL is not a site about ***basic*** English. It is a site about helping people learn (everyday) English as a foreign language. That said, I agree. This belongs on ELL not on ELU.

Comment: @Matt agreed, ELL is not only about the basics of the English language. I phrased the reason poorly but the OP's question is such that any native speaker could give the correct answer within minutes. ELL will (or should) explain *why* the answer is correct.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: _I_ 'd have a job explaining (with any degree of confidence) why 'turn (60 etc)' is in common usage but 'become 60' isn't. As I'm sure you would.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Turning 60" is not one that would automatically spring to my mind, but I'm sure the vast majority of native speakers would suggest: "**I'm** 60 this year" or "**I'll be** 60 next year" or "**I'm going to be** 60 soon" etc. I don't think any native speaker would ever say *become*  This is, in my opinion, an easy question for anyone to answer. Less easy is to explain why, but the OP doesn't seem interested in any explanation.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: I was commenting on your 'ELL will (or should) explain _why_ the answer is correct'. Often the only answer on offer for this type of question is 'because it is'. What often seems to happen is that someone introduces an expression, it becomes popular, but the logic (if any - it may be a quirky choice) behind the choosing of that particular expression rather than an apparently equally eligible alternative becomes lost in time.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest form would be:

> ### I'll be 60 years old next year.

Another option, although a little more awkward<sup>*</sup> in my opinion, would be:

> ### I'll be turning 60 years old next year.

or

> ### I will turn 60 years old next year.

You could also shorten both phrases by omitting "years old", and you should be understood:

> ### I'll be 60 next year.

<sup>*</sup>The "turning" construct sounds a bit more awkward to me, but it can also be slightly more precise, depending on context.  In the general sense, either "I will be 60" or "I will turn 60" will convey the same meaning, but in certain specific contexts, they can be different.

In the strictest sense, saying "I will be 60 next year" simply says "at some point during the next year, I will be 60."  This could be taken to mean that you will start the year, Jan 1, with the age of 60, and some time later, will be 61 years old.

This type of confusion is only likely in specific, technical contexts, such as retirement planning, or eligibility for an after-school program ("Participants must be 12 years old before Sept 1"), etc.

But to avoid such confusion, if it matters in your particular context, you can use the "I will turn 60 next year" form.