# Which is the correct verb to use, "become" or "turn", when referring to one's age?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Which of the following statements is more common and why?

> 1. I became 20 yesterday.
> 2. I turned 20 yesterday.

Comment: They are both correct and mean the same thing. But they might be used in different contexts. I think I would tend to use *turn*, if I was stressing the fact of a person's age, such as with children or teenagers. But also I might use it with landmark birthdays such as 40, 50, 60, 70 and heaven forbid, if I make it 80!

Comment: I became 20 does not show up on a Google Corpus English search, while I turned 20 spikes in popularity from 1980. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+became+20%2C+I+turned+20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20turned%2020%3B%2Cc0 Became is also absent with 30, 40, 50 and 60. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+became+20%2C+I+became+30%2C+I+became+40%2C+I+became+50%2C+I+became+60&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: Probably the most common way of saying this is the counter-intuitive 'I was 20 yesterday'. Semelfactive _be_!

Comment: Related: *[I'll be 60 years old next year](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124648)*

Answer (score 4):

"Became" would be understood, but "turned" is the normally used verb, at least in the US. "Was" does not suit this context; it would more likely be used to reference the distant past; i.e., I was 20 when the Beatles arrived in America.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion *turn* would be an appropriate choice. Both may be used to denote changes. However, *turn* is used when a the process is still in continuation and gradual per se, like aging, while *become* is used when the phrase is more definitive and result oriented. 
For example:

> - What do I have to do to **become** a pilot?
> - He **turned** 100 years old yesterday.